# How to focus on form input after appending it to dom?

Tags: jquery, html

The snippet below adds a form to the page on click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".reply").click(function () {
    var form = '<form id="rform" action="/sendme" method="POST"><input class="title" name="title" type="text" /><textarea rows="8" name="body"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
    $(".placeholder").append(form);
  });
});
```

to the html:

```
 <a class="reply" href="#">Reply</a>
<div class="placeholder">
```

The `Reply` link can appear anywhere on the page. The problem is that after appending the form, the browser jumps to the top of the page.

I'm wondering how to scroll/focus to the `title` input field after appending the form.

I've tried adding `focus()` or `scroll()` after `.append(form)` but none worked. I've also searched SO, but could not find useful answers to similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".reply").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.placeholder').html('');
    var form = '<form id="rform" action="/sendme" method="POST"><input class="title" name="title" type="text" /><textarea rows="8" name="body"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
    $(".placeholder").append(form);
    $("input.title").focus();
  });
});
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="reply" href="#">Reply</a>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
```

First , if you donot want it to scroll to top.  Use the  `event.preventDefault();`

Second , use `$('.placeholder').html('');` if you donot want repeated comment form on click.

third , `$("input.title").focus();` works just fine. Already tested

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it works

```
  $("[data-scroll-to]").click(function() {
   var form = '<form id="rform" action="/sendme" method="POST"><input class="title" id="id2" name="title" type="text" /><textarea rows="8" name="body"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
      $("#id1").append(form);


  var $this = $(this),
      $toElement      = $this.attr('data-scroll-to'),
      $focusElement   = $this.attr('data-scroll-focus'),
      $offset         = $this.attr('data-scroll-offset') * 1 || 0,
      $speed          = $this.attr('data-scroll-speed') * 1 || 500;

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($toElement).offset().top + $offset
  }, $speed);
  if ($focusElement) $($focusElement).focus();

});
```

https://codepen.io/Thaks123/pen/byWmGo?editors=1111

It works with scroll also.

Answer (score 0):

The page is jumping to the top because you are navigating to an anchor. Remove `href="#"` from the `reply` link. You could replace it with `href="javascript:void(0);"`

You should then be able to use `.focus()` to position the page where you like.

Comment: Or 1) he can put `href="#rform"` or 2) use `button` instead of `a` element

Comment: or leave a element empty